# Javascript - access the embed tag and append text at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, append, embed

in the html source i have the following:

```
<embed width="100%" id="video-player-flash"...
```

**THE embed IS INSIDE AN iframe**

how to access at runtime the embed to append

```
<embed width="100%" id="video-player-flash" allownetworking="internal"...
```

thanks

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    document.video-player-flash.innerHTML += 'allownetworking=&quot;internal&quot;';
});
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    document.getElementById("video-player-flash").innerHTML += 'allownetworking=&quot;internal&quot;';
});
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var playerep = document.getElementById('video-player-flash');
    playerep.setAttribute("allownetworking", "internal");    
});
</script>
```

what's wrong?

**i think the problem is that youtube video is on another domain (youtube.com)... so how to get all the content of the iframe after the loading and then replace it completely adding 'allownetworking="internal"'. Is it possible?**

Comment: @gpojd question updated... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#video-player-flash").attr("allownetworking", "internal");
    });
</script>
```

You can read up on the jQuery `attr` function here: 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

As your using jQuery there's no need to use `document.getElementById` - you'd be better of using the jQuery selectors when you want select elements in your page.

Comment: it doesn't work...maybe the problem is that inside an iframe?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $("#video-player-flash").attr("allownetworking", "internal");    
});
</script> is it correct? doesn't work...

Comment: You're embedded video is inside an IFRAME and this code is outside of the IFRAME?

Comment: yes, outside...'cause the iframe is generated by external script

Comment: Ok well try: document.frames["MyIFrameID"].$("#video-player-flash").attr("allownetworking", "internal");

Comment: now it's <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.frames["youtubeDivPlayer"].$("#video-player-flash").attr("allownetworking", "internal");
    });
</script> but into the html source don't see allownetworking...

Comment: well, the iframe id is youtubeDivPlayer for sure and the same for embed id, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'youtubeDivPlayer' of undefined
(anonymous function)
b.extend.ready
u

Comment: Is `youtubeDivPlayer` definately the frame ID?

Comment: example: http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/ the difference is that i'm into an embed inside other divs...

Comment: i think the problem is that youtube video is on another domain (youtube.com)... so how to get all the content of the iframe after the loading and then replace it completely adding 'allownetworking="internal"'. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok you probably can't then due to the fact it's cross domain.